# angularjs directive pass parameter out controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am sending a controller method to directive. I want to get parameter frpm direvtive like events.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/44jokt84/)

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("outCtrl", function($scope){
        $scope.callOut = function(pramFromDirective){
        console.log(pramFromDirective);
    }
})


app.directive("myDir", function(){
  return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                call: "&"
        },
            controller: function($scope){
            $scope.call({message: 444});
        }
  }
})
```

I want to send a parameter to `outCtrl.callOut()` method. But it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the parameter in the template, with the same name as the property of the object you pass to `$scope.call()`. Since you call it as `$scope.call({message: 444})` do:

```
<my-dir call="callOut(message)"></my-dir>
```

Comment: But a developer that using my directive can not know my inner parameter name in this stuation. He can send a wrong name

Comment: This is indeed a problem, but a different one. Can be solved with documentation or code conventions. Angular is doing it through documentation (see the `$event` argument of e.g. [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) - check out the "Arguments" section).

Answer (score 0):

Your template isn't quite correct. You need to have the parameter in your callback method binding match the name of the object key you use in your directive match exactly.

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="outCtrl">
    <my-dir call="callOut(message)"></my-dir>
  </div>
</div>
```

Angular isn't actually passing the parameter straight through. It maps the object keys from your directive function call parameter `$scope.call({ message: 444 })` to parameter names of the method in the template `call="callout(message)"`.

Comment: But a developer that using my directive can not know my inner parameter name in this stuation. He can send a wrong name.